# What focal length is typical for Wedding Photography?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, focal-length, wedding

I am looking to start a wedding photography business and would like to understand what the best length is for the lenses.

Comment: There is no "best length" for the lense.

Comment: Physical or focal length?  You'll need to specify what type of camera it's going to be attached to, to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Focal length/. Nikon D610

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prepare best for my first wedding photography event?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29723/how-do-i-prepare-best-for-my-first-wedding-photography-event)

Comment: Please, pelase, go out and practice! Do not go to a wedding based on what you have read on a forum, please! Go to your comunity temple, talk to the capellan or pastor.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if you're asking questions like this, you're not ready to start a wedding photography business. See lensrentals.com's ["FWIGTEW and other First Wedding Acronyms" article](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2010/07/fwigtew-and-other-first-wedding-acronyms/)

Comment: Have you asked this question of the lead shooter for whom you've shot second at weddings?

Comment: Lenses will usually fall in the 10mm to 600mm range :-). Often 17mm to 300mm. On an APSC camera a good quality 24mm-70mm will be useful but you'll regret not having narrower and wider. On a FF 24-70mm may be OK at the bottom end but not good enough at top end by far. ie you want more than one lens, very ideally more than one camera, and lots of time in advance playing under no stress. || If you "only" carried two lenses and two bodies you could do a creditable job in many situations with an APSC camera with suitable quality 24-70mm f/2.8 and 70-200mm f/2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weddings and Events in general are the time when zoom lenses shine. The Zoom is important because you want to be out of the way for the most part. The two lenses to have are 24-70 and 70-200 will cover your entire range. If you can afford it you don't want the kit grade but the pro grade. The kit grade is usually something like 3.5-5.6 meaning it will only get a 3.5 aperture at its widest focal length. A pro grade will have a constant aperture and usually larger (smaller number). Even a constant f4 is better than a variable aperture because when you're zooming in and out you can still lock in the f4 and just let the shutter speed change. An f2 of course is even better than an f4 for a few reasons all based on its ability to let in more light.

- More light means faster autofocus which is good when shooting events.
- More light means more depth of field options which allows a focal point to really separate from other elements.
- More light means you can do indoor weddings easier and on a lower ISO

Comment: "*just let the shutter speed change.*" the same holds true for a variable aperture lens. The automatic metering mode of the camera will take that change into account and calculate the right shutter speed just the same.

Comment: @null that wasn't really the relevant point. When zooming in and out the f4 can stay constant. If you're on a f/3.5-f/5.6 than as soon as you zoom to a length requiring 5.6 then that's going to be your aperture even when you zoom back in. So unless you lock it at the maximum focal length's minimum aperture (5.6) you don't get a constant depth of field.

Comment: You won't get a constant depth of field regardless of the aperture being fixed or not because zooming means changing the focal length which in turn changes depth of field.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I understand how the gear works and though 24 to 70 but had not considered the longer range suggested, but makes sense now.

Comment: More light (from a larger aperture) does not automatically mean faster autofocus, it means more consistent autofocus.

Comment: The biggest advantage of constant aperture zooms is when shooting in **M** exposure mode - you don't have to adjust shutter speed or ISO every time you change focal length. With *Auto ISO* becoming more common when Tv and Av are selected manually, that is becoming less of an advantage. Most constant aperture zoom lenses also have better overall optical performance than most variable aperture lenses.

Comment: @KamenMinkov That depends on the camera. It is possible to program an AF system to vary the sample time used for AF. For example, Canon camera use a slightly longer sample time for *One Shot AF* mode than for *AI Servo AF* mode. One of the factors that may also be included in the firmware running the AF is to vary it based on the lens' maximum aperture.

Comment: Unless you've shot second at more than a few weddings don't even consider shooting one as the lead photographer.